# How do I decode a png image encoded in Base64 and see it on an ImageView?

Tags: java, android, image, png, arrays

My android device requests to the server a png image. The server encodes the image in Base64 and sends it to my device. After that, I decode the Base64 string into a byte array and use BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray() to make a Bitmap image of it. I can't see the image when I add it in an ImageView.

**See below for the code:**

```
JSONObject params = resultObject.getJSONObject("params");
byte[] decodedImageInBytes = Base64.decode(params.getString("image_one"), Base64.DEFAULT);

Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedImageInBytes, 0, decodedImageInBytes.length);
ImageView imageViewOne = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewOne);
imageViewOne.setImageBitmap(myImage);
```

***Edit:***

It seems that my code is okay, I have some problems with the server. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Example of `params.getString("image_one")`, please?

Comment: It's the string of the encoded image in base64.

Comment: I understand that. Could you post an example of such a base64 string?

Comment: Ok, please wait... (I'll be editing this soon)

Comment: Why are you using base64? You could load it binary without problems

Comment: @stefanbachert it's coming through JSON, so presumably it's being sent over HTTP.

Comment: has you bitmap a valid height and width after decoding? I have been decoding base64 images exactly like you without any problems.

Comment: Agreed with @Renard. Your code looks fine (as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/4837293/139010 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/5106670/139010) so my guess is that the data is corrupted or not in the expected format.

Comment: I have posted the string. I'm not sure if the height and width is correct...

Comment: @Xonarial : decode your string http://www.base64decode.org/ and see what it content

Comment: welcome,but say thanks to @MДΓΓ БДLL and ask for answer i think

Comment: Thanks everyone, especially MДΓΓ БДLL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have decoded your string for you. It is not bitmap data.

```
Unknown error type: [2] include(/home/hospitalit/domains/hospitalitymanager.nl/public_html/demo/application//controllers/global/statistic_images/reservation_guest_rank) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory<br />
on line 45 in file /home/hospitalit/domains/hospitalitymanager.nl/public_html/demo/application/controllers/api/statistics/index.phpUnknown error type: [2] include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '/home/hospitalit/domains/hospitalitymanager.nl/public_html/demo/application//controllers/global/statistic_images/reservation_guest_rank' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php')<br />
on line 45 in file /home/hospitalit/domains/hospitalitymanager.nl/public_html/demo/application/controllers/api/statistics/index.php
```

Comment: Yep, I just saw that too. :D Thanks for your help tough!